# Creating an Arraylist, outputing a new list, and displaying in main method

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, methods

Return the array list in a method and display. Write a method named sumInts that can take a variable number of int arguments and return the sum of these arguments.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class X {
     public static void main(String[] argv) {

    String strAra[] = new String[4]; //{ "Lionel Messi", "Drake", "Adele", "Dwayne Johnson", "Beyonce" };
    strAra[0] = "Lionel Messi";
    strAra[1] = "Drake";
    strAra[2] = "Adele";
    strAra[3] = "Dwayne Johnson";
    strAra[4] = "Beyonce";
    List<String> lList = Arrays.asList(strAra);
    System.out.println("Here is the list:");
    Iterator<String> iterator = lList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
    System.out.println("Here is the new list");
    for (int i = 0; i < lList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(lList.get(i));
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem asks for an `ArrayList` but you're using an array.  Using `Arrays#asList` creates a `List` that cannot be added to or removed from, which you don't want because your `List` needs to be modified at one point.

Comment: That is the only way I can figure out, how to remove one portion of the list and add a new element to it.

Comment: How would I do that? Do you have something I can reference?

Comment: You'll need to figure out another way to create an `ArrayList` that you can add to and remove from.  You can refer to the Java API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: @A.B. you can use the ArrayList "set(int index, E element)" method to replace an element at a specified index.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw OP needs to add an element at index 2, not set one.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Are you referring to first code or second code? Is removing from an array to a list. A quick fix.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Using `List#set` modifies the object at the second index whereas `List#add` will add an object at that index and shift everything over.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Multiple overloaded `List#add` methods exist.

Comment: @JacobG. you're correct. Maybe I've misunderstood OPs requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the "second attempt ",you are putting five strings into the array,but you init the array that the length is four.
You need to change  "new String[4];" to "new String[5];"
I think. = =

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears you are trying to do, you need to instantiate an ArrayList, not turn an Array into a List. Check the Java API out for the different methods and constructors you can call with an ArrayList.

The ArrayList can be instantiated and the data added by doing the following:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then you can add data by doing:

```
arr.add("Lionel Messi");
```

After populating the ArrayList, you can use the ArrayList's methods of add(element, index) and remove(index) to manipulate the data.